# error reading saved cache and system table while starting Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I've been coming across the following exception when running Cassandra Daemon. I'm running from 1.2 trunk.

```
WARN 14:47:51,038 error reading saved cache /home/manuzhang/cassandra/saved_caches/system-local-KeyCache-b.db
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache.loadSaved(AutoSavingCache.java:141)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:237)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:340)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:312)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.initCf(Table.java:332)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.<init>(Table.java:265)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:110)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:88)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemTable.checkHealth(SystemTable.java:284)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:168)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:318)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:361)
```

here's where caches are saved:

```
manuzhang@manuzhang-U24E:~/cassandra/saved_caches$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 manuzhang manuzhang 156 Aug  7 13:09 system-local-KeyCache-b.db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 manuzhang manuzhang  60 Aug  7 13:09 system-schema_columnfamilies-KeyCache-b.db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 manuzhang manuzhang  60 Aug  7 13:09 system-schema_columns-KeyCache-b.db
```

Also, fail to load system table files.

```
ERROR 17:03:16,637 Fatal exception during initialization
org.apache.cassandra.config.ConfigurationException: Found system table files, but they    couldn't be loaded!
at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemTable.checkHealth(SystemTable.java:303)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:201)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:349)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:392)
```

Now I'm able to reproduce the loading system table failure for every **three** runs of Cassandra (I clean up all the files afterwards). The exception is thrown here:

```
/**
 * One of three things will happen if you try to read the system table:
 * 1. files are present and you can read them: great
 * 2. no files are there: great (new node is assumed)
 * 3. files are present but you can't read them: bad
 * @throws ConfigurationException
 */
public static void checkHealth() throws ConfigurationException
{
    Table table;
    try
    {
        table = Table.open(Table.SYSTEM_TABLE);
    }
    catch (AssertionError err)
    {
        // this happens when a user switches from OPP to RP.
        ConfigurationException ex = new ConfigurationException("Could not read system table!");
        ex.initCause(err);
        throw ex;
    }
    ColumnFamilyStore cfs = table.getColumnFamilyStore(LOCAL_CF);

    String req = "SELECT cluster_name FROM system.%s WHERE key='%s'";
    UntypedResultSet result = processInternal(String.format(req, LOCAL_CF, LOCAL_KEY));

    if (result.isEmpty() || !result.one().has("cluster_name"))
    {
        // this is a brand new node
        if (!cfs.getSSTables().isEmpty())
            throw new ConfigurationException("Found system table files, but they couldn't be loaded!");

        // no system files.  this is a new node.
        req = "INSERT INTO system.%s (key, cluster_name) VALUES ('%s', '%s')";
        processInternal(String.format(req, LOCAL_CF, LOCAL_KEY, DatabaseDescriptor.getClusterName()));
        return;
    }

    String savedClusterName = result.one().getString("cluster_name");
    if (!DatabaseDescriptor.getClusterName().equals(savedClusterName))
        throw new ConfigurationException("Saved cluster name " + savedClusterName + " != configured name " + DatabaseDescriptor.getClusterName());
}
```

The three runs correspond exactly with the three conditions in the comment.

"No files are there" in the first run since it is a brand new node.

In the second run, "files are there and you can read them".

In the third run, "files are there but you can not read them" and I've checked that both `result.isEmpty()` and `result.one.has("cluster_name")` return `false`.

Actually, I'm confused with the exception "couldn't be loaded". What does it mean? I don't think it's a file system permission issue since r/w permissions are granted to the current user.

The above problems go away after I delete all related files but I don't want to do it every time running Cassandra.

This has been afflicting me for quite a while.

An unrelated issue is that I don't think Cassandra@stackoverflow has received enough attention from the community. Do you agree?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: why are you running cassandra trunk, and not a released version?

Comment: @sbridges If you download the codebase following the Cassandra wiki, that's what you get; And I can also read about something new like virtual nodes

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem with an official release, http://cassandra.apache.org/download/

Comment: @sbridges haven't tried yet. Will there be a difference? Even so, that won't solve my problem with the trunk.

Comment: Try to reproduce it with a released version.  I don't know how stable trunk is, but it could easily have a bug.

Comment: @sbridges I can't. The column family causing problem above doesn't even exist in 1.1.4.

Comment: which column family isn't in 1.1.4?  Why are you trying to interact with cassandra classes directly, and not through CQL or thrift.  I'm really not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @sbridges  "local" in system keyspace. I'm reading through the codebase. What am I trying to accomplish? I don't know. But the problem is there so I can't evade it.

Comment: the issue seems to have gone away with the latest pull. thank you for your time and attention. I sent the issue to mailing list but got no reply. I really like stackoverflow but it appears to me the community guys don't hang out here

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in 2 scenarios.

1. I tried changing the partitioner without removing the cluster's data (cant do that) Also view [mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.cassandra.user/9709) for explanation.
2. I ran the cassandra process as a superuser the first time it was started `sudo ./cassandra` which created the necessary data/log/cache directories with permissions only for the superuser, and then restarted cassandra and ran the process as regular user (and thus didn't have permission to use files in the directories created by the process run by the superuser).

I know you solved the problem, but this might be useful for other developers.